# In rails 4.2, how to display a form for preview but ensure it cannot be submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, authenticity-token

I'd like to have a a form view that can, depending on circumstances, have submit functionality disabled in a bullet-proof way so that even a clever user could not edit the HTML source (via a browser extension) to re-add the submit button.

It seems one way to do that might be to somehow inject an invalid authenticity token that replaces the (valid) rails-generated one, so that even if a user somehow re-adds the submit button (by editing the HTML via a browser extension) it would still be an invalid submission.

My thought is to have some logic in the view:

```
- if @form_disabled   # set by controller
  - somehow_invalidate_the_authenticity_token?
```

How might one 'break' Rails form submission?

The purpose of doing this, instead of rendering the preview in a :show action, is to have the exact same view displaying both the live-form and the dead-form.

Comment: Are you using `form_for`? then use something like `form_for ... authenticity_token: false do |f|`

Comment: I think that does the opposite of what I want, eg, makes doesn't that make it easier to submit a form, not impossible to submit as I want?

Comment: If the form does not have the token, then when rails tries to validate it against the one saved in session the controller action will not be called. But the easiest way to verify it is testing, right?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use [pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit).

It's pretty simple, and has few lines of code if you need to know how it works.

I'd start to write the code here, but I realize that the example at the readme fit your needs.

At the application controller add [this](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#rescuing-a-denied-authorization-in-rails)

At the folder `app/policies` put the class [PostPolicy](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#policies), of course, you must replace "Post" with the name of your controller in singular (even if you have not a model with that name). The `update?` (and `create?`) actions should return `true/false` to indicate if user is allowed or not.

A few lines down on the readme, you will find the `PostsController#update` action, which call to `authorize` with the record before the update. I think you want do the same with create (then you need a `create?` method at the policy class).

Pundit needs `current_user` controller method, if you don't have it. Just follow the [user customization](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#customize-pundit-user) instructions.

Of course, `new` and `edit` actions don't call `authorize` because they are allowed to everybody. Only the `POST` & the `PUT/PATCH` actions are forbidden.

Yes, it's more than a surgery of one line of code. But it's simple and the right way of give access to users.

Answer (score 0):

After reading my other answer, I start thinking that you can do the same that Pundit does at the controller:

```
def update
  if <unauthorized user>
    flash[:alert] = "You are not authorized to perform this action."
    redirect_to(request.referrer || root_path)
  else
    # all the update stuff
    # ...
  end
end
```